# "Washington, DC" in latin

Tags: contemporary-latin, place-names

Is there a more-or-less commonly accepted translation of "Washington, DC" (i.e., the city, but I would assume the same word would work for the state) in [contemporary-latin](/questions/tagged/contemporary-latin)? I'll happily use *DC* for *districtus columbiae* for the "DC" part, but I haven't been able to find much for the "Washington" part.

[Searching hereabouts](https://latin.stackexchange.com/search?q=washington+%5Bcontemporary-latin%5D) yielded [Vasitonia](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/833/3330), but [that does not seem to be very common](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffsb&q=latin+vasitonia).

(Background: the kids are making a movie as a school project on the two Capitols. The German and English parts are easier than the Latin ones... but also less interesting.)

Comment: Latin Wikipedia goes with [Vasi**n**tonia](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasintonia_\(civitas\)).

Comment: Related: [Quomodo “Bloomington” reddere?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4758/quomodo-bloomington-reddere)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An *official* source for modern Latin names of cities is Catholic dioceses. In ecclesiastical Latin, the demonym of Washington is **[Vashingtonensis](http://www.catholic-hierarchy.org/diocese/dwash.html)** (with *sh*, which is weird, and *ng*), thus the city should be

> **Vashingtonia**.

As per [Latin Wikipedia](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasingtonia_(D.C.)) (not to be treated too seriously as a source, but the sources cited sometimes can), it may as well be **Washingtonium**, **Vasingtonia** (without *h*), **Vasingtonium**, and apparently **Vasintonia** (without *g*). DC is in fact quoted as **Districtus Columbiae**.

The linked Vasitonia seems to be a typo to me. That —and, well, Latin too— could explain the small number of results in your search.

**Update:**  below is an excerpt from Acta Apostolicae Sedis, from [June 2006](http://www.vatican.va/archive/aas/documents/2007/giugno%202007.pdf), when Donald Wuerl was named archbishop of Washington, DC as **Metropolitana Ecclesia Vashingtonensis** (with *sh* and *ng*).

[image]

Comment: Do you have an official source that that is the Latin name of the archdiocese? FWIW, searching Latin documents on vatican.va, I found several different forms: Washingtonia, Vashingtonia, [Vasintonia, -ae](https://www.google.com/search?ei=_7s_YO7hJ9Sr5NoPi_uHwA0&q=Vasintoniae+site%3Avatican.va), and [Vasingtonia](https://www.google.com/search?ei=A7w_YOOsB-qp5NoPhcO6yAc&q=Vasingtoniae+site%3Avatican.va). The latter seems to be part of a formula with "degenti," i.e. "residing in Washington."

Comment: @brianpck: good point. [Here is a letter from John Paul II to *Archiepiscopo Vashingtonensi*.](http://www.vatican.va/content/john-paul-ii/la/letters/1996/documents/hf_jp-ii_let_19960520_50-anniv-hickey.html)

Comment: @brianpck good question. I just trusted CH. Although not official, I consider it a serious source that's kept very up to date

Comment: @brianpck fixed! I also looked for the current bishop's appointment, but the source I found only had the AAS texts up to 2018